# Matching string of numbers and letters and of a specific length

Tags: python, regex

So I have this exercise and can't solve it:

I can only accept a string, if it's constructed of numbers AND letters, has to contain at least one of both; and it has to be 6-8 characters long. The string is only one word.

The first part is fine, though I'm not sure about using match:

```
re.match('([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)', string)
```

but I don't know how to specify the length that it should be the length of both numbers and letters added up. This won't work and I guess it shouldn't anyway:

```
re.match('([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+){6,8}', string)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{6,8}$
```

Explanation:

```
^              //The Start of the string
(?=.*\d)       //(?= ) is a look around. Meaning it
               //checks that the case is matched, but
               //doesn't capture anything
               //In this case, it's looking for any
               //chars followed by a digit.
(?=.*[a-zA-Z]) //any chars followed by a char.
[a-zA-Z\d]{6,8}//6-8 digits or chars.
$              //The end of the string.
```

Comment: This worked and the explanation came just in time to stop me overexerting my brain as I was trying to figure it out. Now everything's clear, thanks a lot!

Comment: I've been thinking and I have another question: it can happen that only the first character is a digit and all the rest are letters, or the other way round. In that case your this code wouldn't accept the string, while it would be right. Is there a way to solve that, too? I don't need it now, I'm just interested.

Comment: It would accept the string, because the `*` matches **0** or more